# how to control these static blocks?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, sample-data

I am a newbie in magento, it seems to be an easy question but i spend hours still cannot figure it out..

I installed the sample data for Magento1.9 (attached), the bottom blocks (title in blue color) "Company" and "Connect with us" are two static blocks. But i cannot figure out how they are placed there, neither the CMS-page or other CMS-block have mention them. And i checked all XML files, none of these static blocks are mentioned! Why?
How can I modify, for example, put the "company" block after the "Connect with us" block?

Thanks a lot for anyone can help!
[image: image address the blocks location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pakicle,
Magento is manged block positioning using before and after tags xml file ...

first check what is before and after tags in layout xml

**name :** `This is the name by which other blocks can make reference to the block in which this attribute is assigned` .

**before (and) after**  `These are two ways to position a content block within a structural block. before="-" and after="-" are commands used to position the block accordingly at the very top or very bottom of a structural block.`

As  footer  link are manged from below codes

**Company:**

```
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" >
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
    </block>
```

**Quick link:**

```
     <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
        </block>
```

**Account:**

```
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
        </block>
```

**Connect with US:**

```
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_sm" after="footer_links2">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_sm</block_id></action>
    </block>
```

As you want footer link sort order

```
QuickLink>My Account>Connected with Us>Company
```

corresponding block id are `footer_links>footer_links2>cms_footer_links_sm>cms_footer_links`
Now i can ordering these link blocks using  tags.
**Connected with Us->cms_footer_links_sm
Company > cms_footer_links**

I have add before......tags as  **cms_footer_links footer_links2**

```
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" after="footer_links2">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
        </block>
```

know more about layout:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

Answer (score 1):

Company is the block with the handle `footer_links_company` and the connect with us is the block `footer_links_sm`.

The other parts are built on blocks with the name `footer_links` and `footer_links2` via the layout xml.

```
<reference name="footer_links2">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /><title>My Account</title></action>
</reference>
```